# Counting monomials in cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

Let $\Phi_n(x)$ denote the [$n$-th cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). There are numerous properties and utilities of these polynomials. My interest is more basic and in the spirit of

> Tewodros Amdeberhan and Richard P. Stanley, *Polynomial Coefficient Enumeration*, preprint (2008) arXiv:[0811.3652](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3652) ([pdf](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/~tamdeberhan/PCE.pdf)).

Namely, how many non-zero terms $N(\Phi_n(x))$ does $\Phi_n(x)$ have? I suspect this might be hard. So, let's consider a modest problem.

> **Question.** If $p, q, r$ are distinct primes, is there an explicit (or semi-explicit) formula for 
>   $$N(\Phi_{pqr}(x))\,\,?$$

**UPDATE.** If $r=2$, direct calculation shows that $\Phi_{2pq}(-x)=\Phi_{pq}(x)$. Therefore, the result of Carlitz (see Igor's link below) implies the following very special case of my question:
$$N(\Phi_{2pq}(x))=N(\Phi_{pq}(x))=\frac{2(p-u)(uq+1)}p-1.$$

**UPDATE.** I am still waiting for some answers to the question.

Comment: $N(\Phi_n(x))$ is [OEIS sequence A051664](https://oeis.org/A051664).

Answer (score 8):

In a 1966 Monthly paper

*Carlitz, Leonard*, [**The number of terms in the cyclotomic polynomial $F_{pq}(x)$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2314500), Am. Math. Mon. 73, 979-981 (1966). [ZBL0146.26704](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0146.26704).

Carlitz shows that

$$ N(\Phi_{pq}(x)) = \frac{(p-u)(u q + 1)}{p} + \frac{u(pq - uq - 1)}{p},$$ where $q>p$ and $u = -1/q \mod p.$ Perhaps his methods can be extended to more primes, who can say.

Comment: Thanks, Igor! That is a nice resource. Just a simplification: $N(\Phi_{pq}(x))=\frac{2(p-u)(uq+1)}p-1$.